# I want to make an error in eslint when importing a file from index.ts

Tags: typescript, next.js, eslint, typescript-eslint

When importing components under src/components, I want to make sure that an error occurs if the component is not imported from index.ts.
Do you know of any rules or plugins that can accomplish the above in eslint settings?

```
// index.ts (src/components/Forms)
export { Input } from './Input';
export { CheckBox } from './CheckBox';
export { Button } from './Button';
```

```
pages/home.tsx

import { Input,CheckBox,Button } from  "src/components/Forms" // success
import { Button } from "src/components/Forms/Button" //error
import { Input } from "src/components/Forms/Input" //error
```

The current eslintrc.js is described.
Added @typescript-eslint/no-restricted-imports.

```
module.exports = {
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:react-hooks/recommended',
    'plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended',
    'prettier',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: 'detect',
    },
  },
  plugins: ['import', 'no-relative-import-paths'],
  rules: {
    'react/prop-types': 'off',
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
    'jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid': 'off',
    'jsx-a11y/no-onchange': 'off',
    'jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions': 'off',
    'jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment': 'warn',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 'error',
    'no-unused-vars': 'off',
    'no-relative-import-paths/no-relative-import-paths': [
      'error',
      { allowSameFolder: false, rootDir: './src' },
    ],
    'prettier/prettier': 'warn',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
    'react/display-name': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-restricted-imports"': [
      'error',
      {
        patterns: [
          {
            group: [
              'src/components/common/*/*',
              '!src/components/common/*/index',
            ],
            message: 'import from .../index.js instead',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

```
//src/pages/index.page.tsx  
import { Select, Button } from 'components/common/Forms';
import { CheckBox } from 'components/common/Forms/CheckBox';
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this maybe:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-restricted-imports": [
      "error",
      {
        "patterns": [
          {
            "group": [
              "src/components/*/*",
              "!src/components/*/index.js"
            ],
            "message": "import from .../index.js instead"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```
// home.tsx

import { CheckBox } from  "src/components/Forms/index.js" // success
import { Button } from "src/components/Forms/Button" // error
import { Input } from "src/components/Forms/Input" // error
```

Docs:

- https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-restricted-imports/
- https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-imports

Comment: Can I just add it to the rules and not have to add anything to the plugin?

Comment: Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-restricted-imports' was not found.eslint(@typescript-eslint/no-restricted-imports)

Comment: An error has occurred.

Comment: In src/pages/home.tsx I wrote import { Input } from "src/components/Forms/Input" but no error.

Comment: @aahhuhuhu You have tagged typescript-eslint. So I assumed you would have already set that up. Refer their guide to get started, and then add this rule to the rules object of your config. https://typescript-eslint.io/docs/

Comment: eslintrc.js has been added. Is there anything wrong?
The error does not occur.

Comment: @aahhuhuhu The paths you've written there have components/common, is that intented? Also, the import will be index.js not index.ts. (In TS, you can either omit the extension or put .js there, .ts will simply not work.) Plus that negation should come at start not before index. (That patterns are like .gitignore, you might waana check reference on that.) Also, how are you checking the errors? Are you running eslint as a part of your build process or just looking at your IDE's squiggles? If it is later, then have you tried restarting your IDE.

Comment: Rebooted the IDE.
Also it is components/common/Forms, not components/Forms. I rewrote it.

The error still does not occur.

Comment: What is wrong with eslintrc.js?

Comment: @aahhuhuhu Can you share your actual imports? The rules are working fine on the playground. PS: it should be `.eslintrc.js`. (leading dot, did you miss that?)

Comment: Import statement added.

Comment: @aahhuhuhu If the imports are just 'component/...' then remove 'src/' from the rules.

Comment: I removed "src" from eslintrc. Updated eslintrc above.

Comment: But it is not an error.

Comment: Thank you very much. I restarted vscode again and it worked fine.

Comment: The components folder is also located in pages/, and the location of the components folder in pages is different from pages/users/components, pages/users/[id]/componets, and so on. In this case, how should I set up the rule?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with this:

```
 '@typescript-eslint/no-restricted-imports': [
      'error',
      {
        paths: [
          {
            name: '.',
            message: '<message here>',
          },
          {
            name: '..',
            message: '<message here>',
          },
        ],
      },
```